# parameter values of usrsctp data received callback became nonsense

Tags: c, callback, sctp

I am recently working on a project based on [usrsctp](https://sctp-refimpl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/KERN/usrsctp/).

When creating a new SCTP socket, one can specify a callback function which will be called when new data is available as shown in the code below.

create a new SCTP socket:

```
struct socket *s = usrsctp_socket(AF_CONN, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP,
                                  sctp_data_received_cb, NULL, 0, sctp);
```

callback function:

```
static int
sctp_data_received_cb(struct socket *sock, union sctp_sockstore addr, void *data,
                  size_t len, struct sctp_rcvinfo recv_info, int flags, void *user_data)
{
  struct sctp_transport *sctp = (struct sctp_transport *)user_data;
  if (sctp == NULL || len == 0)
    return -1;

  fprintf(stdout, "Data of length %u received on stream %u with SSN %u, TSN %u, PPID %u\n",
          (uint32_t)len,
          recv_info.rcv_sid,
          recv_info.rcv_ssn,
          recv_info.rcv_tsn,
          ntohl(recv_info.rcv_ppid));

  if (flags & MSG_NOTIFICATION)
    handle_notification_message(sctp, (union sctp_notification *)data, len);
  else
    handle_rtcdc_message(sctp, data, len, ntohl(recv_info.rcv_ppid), recv_info.rcv_sid);

  free(data);
  return 0;
}
```

This callback function is called properly, but its parameter values are just nonsense. Output of the code above is like

`Data of length 675381504 received on stream 31504 with SSN 34835, TSN 32651, PPID 8470824`

which should have been like

`Data of length 18 received on stream 0 with SSN 0, TSN 4117987333, PPID 50`

I read the source code of usrsctp and found where the callback is called:

```
if (control->spec_flags & M_NOTIFICATION) {
    flags |= MSG_NOTIFICATION;
}
inp->recv_callback(so, addr, buffer, control->length, rcv, flags, inp->ulp_info);
SCTP_TCB_LOCK(stcb);
```

Change it to the code below and recompile the library

```
if (control->spec_flags & M_NOTIFICATION) {
    flags |= MSG_NOTIFICATION;
}
fprintf(stdout, "[LIB] Data of length %u received on stream %u with SSN %u, TSN %u, PPID %u\n",
        control->length,
        rcv.rcv_sid,
        rcv.rcv_ssn,
        rcv.rcv_tsn,
        ntohl(rcv.rcv_ppid));
inp->recv_callback(so, addr, buffer, control->length, rcv, flags, inp->ulp_info);
SCTP_TCB_LOCK(stcb);
```

I can get expected output:

`[LIB] Data of length 18 received on stream 0 with SSN 0, TSN 4117987333, PPID 50`

Why did parameter values become nonsense in the callback function?

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658266/c-usrsctp-callback-parameters-null), but couldn't understand its answer. I am quite sure it is the same issue.

[update1]

the prototype of usrsctp_socket in usrsctp.h:

```
struct socket *
usrsctp_socket(int domain, int type, int protocol,
           int (*receive_cb)(struct socket *sock, union sctp_sockstore addr, void *data,
                             size_t datalen, struct sctp_rcvinfo, int flags, void *ulp_info),
           int (*send_cb)(struct socket *sock, uint32_t sb_free),
           uint32_t sb_threshold,
           void *ulp_info);
```

[update2]

I am quite sure that no extra tricks as suggested in [the old similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658266/c-usrsctp-callback-parameters-null) are needed, since I see no weird castings in the [official examples](https://sctp-refimpl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/KERN/usrsctp/programs/) and they just work well.

for example in echo_server.c:

```
static int
receive_cb(struct socket *sock, union sctp_sockstore addr, void *data,
           size_t datalen, struct sctp_rcvinfo rcv, int flags, void *ulp_info)
{
  char namebuf[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  const char *name;
  uint16_t port;

  if (data) {
    if (flags & MSG_NOTIFICATION) {
      printf("Notification of length %d received.\n", (int)datalen);
    } else {
      switch (addr.sa.sa_family) {
#ifdef INET
      case AF_INET:
        name = inet_ntop(AF_INET, &addr.sin.sin_addr, namebuf, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        port = ntohs(addr.sin.sin_port);
        break;
#endif
#ifdef INET6
      case AF_INET6:
        name = inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &addr.sin6.sin6_addr, namebuf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN),
        port = ntohs(addr.sin6.sin6_port);
        break;
#endif
      case AF_CONN:
#ifdef _WIN32
        _snprintf(namebuf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN, "%p", addr.sconn.sconn_addr);
#else
        snprintf(namebuf, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN, "%p", addr.sconn.sconn_addr);
#endif
        name = namebuf;
        port = ntohs(addr.sconn.sconn_port);
        break;
      default:
        name = NULL;
        port = 0;
        break;
      }
      printf("Msg of length %d received from %s:%u on stream %d with SSN %u and TSN %u, PPID %d, context %u.\n",
             (int)datalen,
             name,
             port,
             rcv.rcv_sid,
             rcv.rcv_ssn,
             rcv.rcv_tsn,
             ntohl(rcv.rcv_ppid),
             rcv.rcv_context);
      if (flags & MSG_EOR) {
        struct sctp_sndinfo snd_info;

        snd_info.snd_sid = rcv.rcv_sid;
        snd_info.snd_flags = 0;
        if (rcv.rcv_flags & SCTP_UNORDERED) {
          snd_info.snd_flags |= SCTP_UNORDERED;
        }
        snd_info.snd_ppid = rcv.rcv_ppid;
        snd_info.snd_context = 0;
        snd_info.snd_assoc_id = rcv.rcv_assoc_id;
        if (usrsctp_sendv(sock, data, datalen, NULL, 0, &snd_info, sizeof(struct sctp_sndinfo), SCTP_SENDV_SNDINFO, 0) < 0) {
          perror("sctp_sendv");
        }
      }
    }
    free(data);
  }
  return (1);
}
```

Comment: I don't think so and I have added the prototype of usrsctp_socket to the question.

Comment: It is reasonable, I will try it. But in official [examples](https://sctp-refimpl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/KERN/usrsctp/programs/), I have seen none of these casting things and they just work well.

Comment: Hi, @joachim-pileborg, I have updated my question again. I still insist that it has nothing to do with the 'addr' parameter.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured out why myself. It is silly but I will post the solution here in case someone would need it.

The defination of union sctp_sockstore (type of the second parameter of the callback function) is shown below.

```
union sctp_sockstore {
#if defined(INET)
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
#endif
#if defined(INET6)
    struct sockaddr_in6 sin6;
#endif
    struct sockaddr_conn sconn;
    struct sockaddr sa;
};
```

INET and INET6 are defined in usrsctp library but not in my code, since I handcrafted the Makefile and omitted them. The parameters were shifted (like 16bit) because of different sizes of the unions and so became nonsense.

Defining INET and INET6 (especially INET6) when you compile your own code solves the problem.